# SQLite optimization using transactions

Tags: ios, sqlite, optimization, transactions

I created an iOS app that, when user taps on a button, a thread will be created and the thread will execute `SELECT` statements for 50 times. I read about an optimization technique from http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html#transactions It wrote, (emphasis mine)

> Unless already in a transaction, each
>   SQL statement has a new transaction
>   started for it. This is very
>   expensive, since it requires
>   reopening, writing to, and closing the
>   journal file for each statement. This
>   can be avoided by wrapping sequences
>   of SQL statements with `BEGIN
>   TRANSACTION;` and `END TRANSACTION;`
>   statements. **This speedup is also
>   obtained for statements which don't
>   alter the database.**

So, I tried adding the `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` at the beginning of the thread and `END TRANSACTION;` and the end of the thread, and I found that it reduced the running time by half. However, since it's in threads, sometimes a situation like this happens:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION from thread 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION from thread 2
END TRANSACTION from thread 2
END TRANSACTION from thread 1
```

The second `BEGIN` and the second `END` statements will fail. Therefore, I want to move the `BEGIN`/`END` statements out of threads
 i.e. call the `BEGIN` only once at the start of the application and `END` at the end of the application. But I'm not sure if it will use up memory? i.e. open the transaction thoughout the application's life time without committing it. The database is read-only because it's bundled with the app.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a read-only database, try opening it with

```
sqlite3_open_v2("path/to/database", &connection,
                SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX, 0);
sqlite3_exec(connection,
             "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE; PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF;",
             0, 0, &errmsg);
```

then sharing the `connection` object among all your threads.  That *ought* to get you all the performance benefits of leaving a transaction open, without having to leave a transaction open.  (You might not need the second command.  I'd like to think SQLite was clever enough to recognize that it didn't need locking or journaling for a read-only connection, but I don't trust it to be.)